# DST while using EST time zone in java code

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst

I have a piece of code wriiten in java that gives me the correct time using EST time zone as below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date());
        System.out.println(dateTime);

    }
}
```

Here i wanted to add the code for Daylight Saving Time with using EST time zone , my output should give me correct time considering EST time zone and daylight savings also.

Any help Appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani i read that question and its solutions , it doesn't answer my question asked here

Comment: Considering day light saving in time zone. Thats what is asked and answered in the other question. How yours differ from that question?

Comment: As an aside, avoid the long outdated classes `Date` and friends if you can. You can. In particular, avoid `TimeZone.setDefault()`, it may break functionality not only in your own program, but in other programs running in the same JVM. I recommend `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"))`.

Comment: Just to stress what Andy Turner already said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953478/5772882): Avoid three and four letter time zone abbreviations whereever you can. They are ambiguous and not standardized. For example, according to [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) EST may also mean Australian Eastern Standard Time (UTC+10).

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

Use the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Avoid the 3-4 letter codes such as EST. These are not actual time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique! Use [real time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the form of `continent/region`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

I suggest you consider using the standard ISO 8601 formats when generating strings rather than your peculiar format. The standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes when generating/parsing strings.

But if you insist…

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd-HHmmss" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly, `TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")` doesn't observe daylight savings time in the same way that `PST` does. (The same is true of `HST` and `MST`).

Use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")` instead.

Generally, avoid using three-letter time zone abbreviations, as it states in the Javadoc.

Comment: Right idea, but using the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.